# How do you edit protobuf in a request with mitmproxy

Tags: python, encoding, protocol-buffers, mitmproxy

I'm not sure how to go about changing the protobuf data in a request using mitmproxy. I only have a few days of experience with using tools like Charles and mitmproxy. I just need to change one value of the protobuf data. How would I go about doing that? I have this so far

```
def request(self, flow: HTTPFlow):
    if flowfilter.match(self.filter, flow):
        ctx.log.alert(flow.request.path)
        # print(assemble_request(flow.request).decode('utf-8'))
        body = assemble_body(flow.request.data.headers, flow.request.data.content)
        print(bytes(body))

        ctx.log.alert('\n')
```

Not too sure if I'm going in the right direction